# Is the scalar magnetic potential continuous?

Tags: potential

If we have two current-free spaces and separated by a surface current, we can solve the magnetic problem by solving two magnetic scalar potentials and then using matching conditions. My question is, is the general scalar magnetic potential continuous? Why?

Comment: As long as the magnetic medium can be modeled as linear, then the magnetic permeability is piecewise constant and satisfies $\nabla\cdot(\mu \Phi_{m})=0$, i.e., you can match boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

The potential for a static magnetic problem is defined through
$$
{\bf B} = - \nabla \phi
$$
(or you can define another potential for $\bf H$). Then since $\nabla \cdot {\bf B} = 0$ we have Laplace's equation for $\phi$ and that is why it is useful: we have lots of good methods for solving Laplace's equation. (Of course it won't work if $\nabla \times {\bf B} \ne 0$; in that case one should adopt another approach.)

The above equation implies that the answer to your question is that $\phi$ is continuous if and only if $\bf B$ is finite. At a boundary such as a surface you expect to find finite $\bf B$. At a current-carrying wire of arbitarily small radius, on the other hand, $\bf B$ can diverge.

Answer (score 0):

A potential is essentially an integral of work to carry a particle (magnetic or electric one) from an infinite distance up to the point you need to know the potential value. If the force making the work is not a Dirac's Delta, then the integral (i.e. the potential) must be a continuous function.

Comment: Careful: this isn't quite right for magnetic fields because it is not a case of work being done. The potential is here simply a mathematical device useful for finding $B$ (and $\bf H$) field in static problems.